# When I start the Emulator in android studio chipmunks 2021.3.1 . My Emulator doesn't comes online and loading do not ends

Tags: android-studio

[image]

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to fix this and make the emulator come online . I reinstalled the SDK and the emulator also but nothing works .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you not having enough free disk space it takes too many time to run the  emulator and will not start unless at least 2 GB is free. check to see that you have free disk space. or you can run the project in your mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

I Really was running low on my own RAM. The emulator was using android R and my laptop just wasn't able to load the emulator because of its size I dropped the version of android and now it is working fine. ☺☺☺